# Call original VueJS mixin method from overridden implementation

Tags: vue.js, inheritance, mixins

OK, i have a web page with some steps for the user and a mixin that handle those steps properties and logic, like current/next step value, checks to enable user advancing from each step to the next, etc.

Now i have to add a new functionality to be executed only after a certain step, so what i would like to be able to do is to call the original mixin method that is called everytime the user advance to the next step to add this functionality.

To be more clear, the mixin is (obviously) used in many pages of the webapp, so i would like to override the culprit mixin method in the component extending it, call the original mixin method to reuse its logic and then call oher methods for the new functionality.

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 1):

##### The previous answer does not work, in many cases...

you can directly access the function from the import but you need to bind the scope to `this` so the function uses your component data and/or other overriden functions

```js
// Mixin.js
export default {
  methods: {
    aMethod() {
      //...
    }
  }
}


// Component.vue
import Mixin from './Mixin'

export default {
  //...
  mixins: [Mixin],
  methods: {
    aMethod() {
     // you need to bind the method to `this` when running so that the mixin uses your component data.
      Mixin.methods.aMethod.call(this);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

if the mixin you are importing is already a vue constructor, this can happend if you used Vue.extend to create the mixin, in this case you need to use the `options` to access your method
You can access the mixin function using the options of the mixin

```js
// Mixin.js
export default Vue.extend({
  extends: OtherComponent
  methods: {
    aMethod() {
      //...
    }
  }
})


// Component.vue
import Mixin from './Mixin'

export default {
  //...
  mixins: [Mixin],
  methods: {
    aMethod() {
     // you need to bind the method to `this` when running so that the mixin uses your component data.
      Mixin.options.methods.aMethod.call(this);
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, try it so:

```
// MyMixin.js
export default {
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      //...
    }
  }
}

// Component.vue
<script>
import MyMixin from 'path-to-mixins/MyMixin'

export default {
  //...
  mixins: [MyMixin],
  methods: {
    // there is overrinding you mixin method called myMethod
    myMethod() {
      // then some logic before to use your mixin method
      // and call your mixin method as below
      MyMixin.methods.myMethod()
    }
  }
  //...
}
</script>
```